# Windows Service customise ServiceName from web.config

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

For testing our development we want to be able to install 3 copies of the same windows service on the **same machine** to replicate the 3 stages of our testing. Alpha, Beta, RC.

I want to be able to specify this in the app.config files so we can bootstrap the installutil program from Octopus for example.

The example from the link ( [Multiple Windows Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21320/Multiple-Instance-NET-Windows-Service)) is for .NetFramework Version 2 and when i try and duplicate the code which finds the correct .config file the compiler doesn't understand "MultipleInstanceInstaller". Is there a different implementation in .NET4.5 to find the app.config from within the ProjectInstaller?

```
Assembly service = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MultipleInstanceInstaller));
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(service.Location);
```

Comment: cool, if you reply ill accept your answer so this question is closed.@oleksii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the code, compiled it using VS2012 and .NET 4.5 - all compiles fine.

If you trying to implement the same approach in your code, the `MultipleInstanceInstaller` should correspond to your installer class name, for example `MyInstallerClass`